# How To User Image and User Name In Sliding Menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

[image]I M new On Android 
I created Sliding Menu Drawer Using Actionbar sherlock Library

Its Working Fine But I want Show User Logged Image and His Name ..with Layout On Top Of Sliding Menu Drawer .i really want to create But I failed To create ..Please Help me tell Me How TO Create Which I want ..please

i will Appreciate answer
thanks in advance

```
i want To Show Sliding Menu Like This image Example
```

Comment: Hey, your question is not very detailed. Could you maybe post a picture of what you want to reach. Also it would be great if you could show us your proceedings so far. Are you searching for something like that: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: @Anthea..wait I upadat Image example ..What I want

Comment: @Anthea i updated My Image Example View In Question

Comment: you want to all complete for your question form try in Google don't be lazy. if you really developer you can make it.

Comment: @user3391727...i tried ...And I created Sliding Menu Using Actionbar Library ..i tried To Add Pic And Name .I m Unable To Solve My Problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this example

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

It shows you how to implement a Navigation Drawer with a ListView handled by a BaseAdapter. At the very beginning it tells you to define the layout for your Drawer. Here you can add the layout of your Logged In Name.

```
activity_main.xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- ADD YOUR LAYOUT HERE!!-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For the rest please follow the tutorial in the link.

Comment: Will it Work? ...@Anthea coz I M using Actionbarsherlock Library For Slidng Menu ...I will Remove

Comment: shud i only Add ImageView TextView ...or i shud Add this With LinearLayout

Comment: The BaseAdapter only handles the ListView. You put your layout above the ListView thus it's should not influent each other. You might consider putting it in a Linearlayout if you want to have the same background image for both. But this depends on your concrete layout. As far as I have seen it should be no difference if you use actionbar sherlock as you can see in this example: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/

Comment: I just added a Linear Layout With Imageview...
It Showing On Every Fragment ..Not Sliding drawer ..
i Downloaded Source Code .and Did and Add layout Above Listview ...

Comment: i Created With The Help AndroidBegain

Comment: Please Solve My Issue...@Anthea